# Dimming in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, restore

I 've tried to find solution in askubuntu but I couldn't. how can I restore dimming before monitor is going to sleep? It was useful in 12.04. While wathing films I could see that it is going to sleep and stop it by moving a cursor, now in 14.04 there is no dimming. How to restore dimming in ubuntu 14.04? There is no dimming option in 'Brightness and Lock'.

Comment: It would probably be under "Power Options"